# Get wrong thumbnail of PDF using imageFromPDFWithDocumentRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, pdf-generation

I've got a strange problem using imageFromPDFWithDocumentRef to get the cover of my PDF.

The code is as follow.

```
 - (UIImage *)imageFromPDFWithDocumentRef:(CGPDFDocumentRef)documentRef
{
    CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(documentRef, 1);
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMinX(pageRect),CGRectGetMaxY(pageRect));
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);  
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -(pageRect.origin.x), -(pageRect.origin.y));

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationLow);
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pageRef);

    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return finalImage;
}
```

But sometimes the result is like this ("ABC" represent the name of pdf file)

[image]

which I meant to be this.

[image]

I wonder if anyone could give me a hand, and thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not handle the page rotation, this is why the output is rotated is some situations.
Replace this code:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMinX(pageRect),CGRectGetMaxY(pageRect));
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);  
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -(pageRect.origin.x), -(pageRect.origin.y));
```

with this code:

```
switch (rotate) {
    case 0:
        // Translate the origin of the coordinate system at the 
        // bottom left corner of the page rectangle.
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, cropBox.size.height);
        // Reverse the Y axis to grow from bottom to top.
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
        break;
    case 90:
        // Reverse the Y axis to grow from bottom to top.
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
        // Rotate the coordinate system.
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI / 2);
        break;
    case 180:
    case -180:
        // Reverse the Y axis to grow from bottom to top.
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
        // Translate the origin of the coordinate system at the 
        // top right corner of the page rectangle.
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, cropBox.size.width, 0);
        // Rotate the coordinate system with 180 degrees.
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);
        break;
    case 270:
    case -90:
        // Translate the origin of the coordinate system at the 
        // bottom right corner of the page rectangle.
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, cropBox.size.height, cropBox.size.width);
        // Rotate the coordinate system.
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI / 2);
        // Reverse the X axis.
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -1, 1);
        break;
}
```

In my code cropBox is the same with pageRect in your code. A more detailed explanation of how PDF coordinate system is mapped to image/screen coordinate system is shown in this article on my blog (this code is taken from there): http://ipdfdev.com/2011/03/23/display-a-pdf-page-on-the-iphone-and-ipad/

Comment: That's really a timely help! Could you please tell me how to get the rotate in your code?

Comment: int rotate = CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle(pageRef);

Comment: I can hardly describe how much you've helped me. Thank you so much and it's solved perfectly!